# Is there a known physical crystal for each space group?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, x-ray-crystallography

Group theory tells us that there are 230 crystallographic spaces possible in 3D space.  Is there physically at least one crystal known to form every in each space group, or are certain space groups still "missing" crystals?